# WinRT: how to keep datasource viewmodel in sync with UI

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In the default project template for the GridView, we have a grouped data source that gets bound to the DefaultViewModel and eventually to the GridView.  The datasource is an ObservableCollection.

When I make updates to the underlying data model (add or remove items), the NotifyCollectionChanged gets called and the UI gets updated.  However, sometimes I need to completely update the model by re-querying the db with a different 'filter' on the data.  This requires rebinding of the Data Source to DefaultViewModel, causing the UI to flicker badly (and it's quite slow).

Is there a better way to 're-bind' the data without killing the UI? would async updates work here?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you replace the items in the VM rather than the whole VM itself?

Comment: Tried that by doing: MySource.Clear(); forach(var item in db) MySource.Add(item);

Same results with sluggish UI update.

Comment: Are you adding them to the VM one at time like that all the time?  Every time an item is added to the collection it sends a `NotifyPropertyChanged`, so that would be a significant performance issue.